# "Task not serializable" trying to parse JSON

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, jupyter-notebook, apache-toree

While

```
import play.api.libs.json._

case class Person(name: String, lovesPandas: Boolean)
implicit val personFormat = Json.format[Person]

val text = """{"name":"Sparky The Bear", "lovesPandas":true}"""

val jsonParse = Json.parse(text)
val result = Json.fromJson[Person](jsonParse)
result.get
```

works on the Jupyter notebook with Apache Toree kernel,

```
import org.apache.spark._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

case class Person(name: String, lovesPandas: Boolean)
implicit val personReads = Json.format[Person]

val text = """{"name":"Sparky The Bear", "lovesPandas":true}"""

val input = sc.parallelize(List(text))
val parsed = input.map(Json.parse(_))
val result = parsed.flatMap(record => {    
    personReads.reads(record).asOpt
})
result.filter(_.lovesPandas).map(Json.toJson(_)).saveAsTextFile("files/out/pandainfo.json")
```

returns

```
Name: org.apache.spark.SparkException
Message: Task not serializable
StackTrace: org.apache.spark.util.ClosureCleaner$.ensureSerializable(ClosureCleaner.scala:304)
[...]
```

even though said example is derived from https://github.com/databricks/learning-spark/blob/master/src/main/scala/com/oreilly/learningsparkexamples/scala/BasicParseJson.scala

I understand that objects passed to the other nodes need to be serialized and this seems not to be possible. So is there something wrong with the example or am I doing something wrong? How do I fix this?

---

By the way

```
import org.apache.spark._
import play.api.libs.json._
import play.api.libs.functional.syntax._

val text = """{"name":"Sparky The Bear", "lovesPandas":true}"""

case class Person(name: String, lovesPandas: Boolean)

val input = sc.parallelize(List(text))
val parsed = input.map(Json.parse(_))
val result = parsed.flatMap(record => {
    implicit val personReads = Json.format[Person]
    personReads.reads(record).asOpt
})
result.collect
```

will result in

```
Name: org.apache.spark.SparkException
Message: Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 3.0 in stage 0.0 (TID 3) had a not serializable result: play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$1
Serialization stack:
    - object not serializable (class: play.api.libs.json.OFormat$$anon$1, value: 
[...]
```

I used `result.collect` to test if this part of the code is correct.

**Additionally**, if I write

```
result. filter(_.lovesPandas).map{Json.toJson(_)}.saveAsTextFile("files/out/pandainfo.json")
```

instead of `result.collect` I get

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:166: error: No Json serializer found for type Person. Try to implement an implicit Writes or Format for this type.
                      Json.toJson(_)
                                 ^
StackTrace:
```

so I guess have to declare `Person` to be `Serializable`. However, adding `extends Serializable` to it at the end has no effect while `with Serializable` throws the error

```
Name: Compile Error
Message: <console>:2: error: ';' expected but 'with' found.
       case class Person(name: String, lovesPandas: Boolean) with Serializable
                                                             ^
```

Comment: `with` is for extending multiple traits... you need `extends Serializable`

Comment: I'm not sure Spark's serializable has anything much to do with Java's Serializable so just adding "extends Serializable" isn't going to do anything. Also, does the exact code on the example page you referenced work for you? (i.e. without any of your changes)?

Comment: @TheArchetypalPaul Spark doesn't have its own Serializable attribute. It looks for the Java serializable when running it's CloserCleaner.

Comment: OK, but in any case, just bunging an "extends Serializable" on the end isn't going to fix anything. I'd like to know if the unmodified example works for the OP....

Comment: Case classes automatically implement `Serializable`, theres no need to extend them.

Comment: It won't help because the `Person` class isn't the one causing trouble.

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov, yes, that's what I meant.

Answer (score 0):

I'll go by hunch and say the value returned by `Json.format` isn't serializable.

To get around it, you can declare the value inside `flatMap`:

```
val result = parsed.flatMap(record => {    
  val personReads = Json.format[Person]
  val jsValue = Json.parse(record)
  personReads.reads(jsValue).asOpt
})
```

## Edit

I think what's causing trouble is the fact that `Json.parse` returns `JsValue` which isn't serializable.

You can narrow this down to a single `map`:

```
sc
  .parallelize(List(text))
  .map(record => {
    val personReads = Json.format[Person]
    val jsValue = Json.parse(record)
    personReads.reads(jsValue).asOpt
  })
 .filter(_.lovesPandas)
 .map(Json.toJson(_).toString)
 .saveAsTextFile("files/out/pandainfo.json")
```

Comment: @Make42 Can you post the full stack trace with the error msg when running this code? I want to see the object hierarchy Spark prints out.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by saying "narrow this down to a single `map`". Do you mean I should get rid of `flatMap` and reduce it into the single `map`? Also, with your code I get `Message: <console>:163: error: type mismatch;
 found   : String
 required: play.api.libs.json.JsValue
                  personReads.reads(record).asOpt` If you really want to fuse the `map` and the `flatMap`, you have to write `personReads.reads(Json.parse(record)).asOpt` and you are back with my old error message.

Comment: @Make42 You have a `map` which iterates over all string elements in the text file, why do you need to first create a `JsValue` and then turn it into an object instead of parsing it to your case class directly in a single iteration.

Comment: @Make42 See my edited code. I added the `Json.parse` line to produce a `JsValue`

Comment: Yes, that is what I though (that you forgot `Json.parse`). I edited my comment accordingly, but you were quicker ;-). Anyway: As you can read in my last comment: This only causes the well known error `No Json serializer found for type Person.`.